# Cheap Xbox One games for offline play: are they safe to use?

Tags: xbox-one

I have a new console and I have been watching games in stores like Amazon where they sell very cheap games, less than $10. However, these listings say that you can play only offline with the console without connection.

Is there any risk using such games? What are the consequences of these games? Are they reliable?

For example, this game from a store in my country:

https://articulo.mercadolibre.com.co/MCO-465666664-the-witcher-3-wild-hunt-midia-digital-offline-xbox-one-_JM?quantity=1

Comment: It is kind of hard for us to say.  Can you include a link to one of these games on Amazon? And which Xbox are you talking about? Original, 360, or One? You currently have the Original Xbox tag on your question which is an old console.

Comment: Sorry,the title says xbox One, the game is not properly amazon, but a store in my country https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/aclk?sa=L&ai=DChcSEwjps6vQgL7fAhVIWoYKHWapDXMYABADGgJ2dQ&ohost=www.google.com&cid=CAESEeD2hQeZr4Ep89hONHytGeM7&sig=AOD64_0qxjm0_-sXZwytwc9CX5d981f54A&ctype=5&q=&ved=0ahUKEwjzgqPQgL7fAhWHv1kKHc0JCSEQww8IOA&adurl=

Comment: i put the link in the description

Answer (score 2):

Well, the Witcher 3 isn't an online game to begin with, so maybe it's talking about updates...? I personally would steer very clear from anything like this.. sounds like piracy, but you are still paying for it. That said, I know nothing of your region and what the game market is like.

A good rule of thumb, though, is to only buy games from trusted sources, otherwise you could end up with corrupt games, hacked games (the game behaves in strange ways, like super speed), or can even corrupt your console.